# How to write explicity a curve on $S^n$?

Tags: geometry, parametric, spheres

I considered the $n$-sphere $S^n=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}| \space ||x||=1 \}$ and $p\in S^n$.

I want to write down explicity a curve $\sigma$ on $S^n$ passing through $p$  (for example one of the great circle passing through $p=(p_1,...,p_{n+1})$).

How can I write $\sigma$ ? For $S^2$ I would use the spherical coordinates and find the parametric equation. Is there something analogous for $S^n$?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I believe the intersection of a hypersphere and a hyperplane need not be a curve.  It is true only in $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: Indeed; it's (a scaled, translated copy of) $S^{n-1}$.  Is the question just, what's a good parametric representation of $S^{n-1}$?

Comment: @StevenTaschuk Yes, I wanted to write explicity a simple curve on $S^n$ through p, so I thought to the great circle

Comment: I will edit the question